# How to update argument's value of list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a list with three empty objects like:

```js
TimePickerList =[{},{},{}];
```

For example, I want to add 1 and 2 to the first argument of this list like this:

```js
TimePickerList[0].push("1") // I know it's wrong and I can't use push like this.
TimePickerList[0].push("2")
```

And i want to get this:

```js
TimePickerList =[{"1","2"},{},{}];
```

Is there any way to do this? ***I mean, can I update an argument's value?***

Comment: object  contains key/value pairs not only values you would do so: `list[0]["key"]=8;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. I think you looking for an array with arrays.

```js
const t = [[],[]];

t[0].push(1);
t[0].push(2)
console.log(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update values stored in arrays like such:

```js
TimePickerList = [{}, {}, {}];

TimePickerList[0].a = 1;

console.log(TimePickerList)
   // [{ a: 1 }, {}, {}]
```

The reason it wasn't working for you is because you were trying to push a value to an object. If you want to push values then push to an array, therefore using square brackets [] instead of curly braces {}.